# shallow routing update route ,but router.query doesn't return last updated query string?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hi guys i m using next Js v 10.0.5, i using shallow routing for update query String but after updating URL on next call i still get last value of query string i tried everything but  it doesn't work? in following you can see my component ,i used hooks in it.
it always goes to last condition and query does not update after first update except using refresh?

`enter code here`const NumberFilter=({filter})=>{

```
const [mounted,setMounted]=useState(false)
const handleChange=useCallback(_.debounce(selectFilter,1000),[])

const router = useRouter()
const [value,setValue]=useState('')





function selectFilter(value){

    let filter_search=(filter.id+'-'+value+'-'+value)
    let qs= {...router.query}
    let last_qsf=qs['filters'];
    let filters;
    if (value!==null){//add filter
        alert(JSON.stringify(qs))

        if (Array.isArray(last_qsf)){
            alert('is array')
            
            filters=[...last_qsf,filter_search]
        }
        else if (typeof last_qsf==='string'){
            alert('is string')
            let [id,opt,val]=last_qsf.split('-')
            alert(id)
            filters= [last_qsf,filter_search]
        }else{//always comes here without refresh
            alert('undefined')
            filters=[filter_search]
        }
    }
   


        router.push({
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query:{...router.query,filters:filters}
        } ,undefined, { shallow: true })

    


}

return  ( <NumberFormat
            placeHolder={filter.label}
            onValueChange={(values)=> {
                setValue(values.value)

                handleChange(values.value)
            }}
            displayType={'number'}
            value={value}
            thousandSeparator={true}
            className="form-control c-form-builder-input mt-15"
/>)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

at the end i had to use a custom function to get query string in the following you can see my code

```
   let queue=(window.location.href).split('?')
   let queryString={};      
        if (queue.length<2){
          
            return queryString;
        }
        let qs=queue[1]
        qs.replace("?",'')
        let sect_url=qs.split('&')
       
        sect_url.map(q=>{

            let tmp=q.split('=');
            console.log(tmp,'key value query')
            if (queryString.hasOwnProperty(tmp[0])){
                queryString[tmp[0]]=[...queryString[tmp[0]],tmp[1]]
            }else{
                queryString[tmp[0]]=[tmp[1]]
            }
        })
        console.log(queryString,'query string object')
```